# SEO Keywords Blogging in Company Site

Tags: seo, blog, keywords, marketing

I have a question about how to develop SEO contents based on keywords.

Let's say I have 10 keywords I want to rank so I began writing articles for those 10 keywords on my blog. However, there is only so much you can write on the same topic without sounding like a spam blog.

***How do you get around with this problem?***

Answer (score 2):

You should research LSI (latent semantic index) keywords. A quick way to do this is to use the

> ~

in front of a search word in Google. For example `~food`. Google synonyms will be **bolded** e.g. (Restaurants, recipes, nutrition, etc). Another option is the Google Adwords Keyword tool. Put in the phrase you want to write about, and it will generate terms that are somewhat similar.

Comment: keyword tool is excellent -didnt know about it before, thanks